# Which nameserver to use?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I would like some advice about how to manage the DNS in my company.

We have many ways to manage them:
- Directly using the registrar.
- Using our own server (Rackspace Cloud for us).
- Using our website management interface (cPanel).

I'm about to put a new website online and I'm a bit confused... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends which DNS servers have been configured to be authoritative for your domain.

When you register a domain, generally the registrar's servers are configured by default to be the nameservers for your domain.

You can change this, to someone else's DNS service, or run your own.

If you've only got one server, and a small network, use someone else's servers.  You don't want to worry about running a DNS infrastructure yourself.  If there's only one site, and your host/registrar is reasonably well known, use theirs.

In order to bring up a new website, you need to know which servers are hosting the DNS Records for your domain name.  The easiest way to figure this out is to run `whois yoursite.org` and look for the nameserver lines in the response.

This is for example.org

```
Name Server:A.IANA-SERVERS.NET
Name Server:B.IANA-SERVERS.NET
```

Then you'll have some idea where to start looking for your DNS records to change for the new site.

Comment: You can also use `dig example.com NS` to find your current nameservers.

Comment: We have a lot of small websites and the registrar of our company uses is not that good. That's why I think I should transfer the management to Rackspace (I know how to do it) because their interface is better. But I don't what I should do with WHM/cPanel.

Comment: Personally, I hate cPanel with a passion.  In that case, change your ns records to point at Rackspace's dns management, and use theirs?

Comment: Yep I don't know if cPanel is that great but my colleague wanted to use it in order to be more productive... Anyway thanks @Tom O'Connor and everybody, I will try to understand cPanel by myself instead of asking vague questions ;)